# What does express delivery in terms of courier mean? Does it mean 'Expressed' like in Law or it means 'Overnight'?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

What does express delivery in terms of courier mean? Does it mean 'Express' same as in Law I.e. Verbal/written or it means 'Overnight' ?

Comment: Noun 1. Express Mail - mail that is distributed by a rapid and efficient system - [TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Express+delivery)

Comment: "express" in law means '*stated* explicitly'.    How could a *delivery* be stated explicitly?  The source of your confusion is not clear.  Did you look up the meanings of the word **express**??

Comment: express in this context means **moving or being sent fast**. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/express

Answer (score 2):

It definitely does not mean "written".  Nor does it necessarily mean "overnight". **Express** simply means "fast". From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/express):

> 3 a :  traveling at high speed; specifically :  traveling with few or no stops along the way
>
> b :  designed or intended to be used for fast movement or travel
>
> c (1) :  delivered faster than usual  (2) British :  designated to be delivered without delay by special messenger.

**Express delivery** in general simply means *faster than usual delivery*. Specific couriers might have particular services that go by this title. For example, until recently USPS had a service called *Express mail* that guaranteed overnight delivery under certain conditions. The service is now called "Priority Mail Express". But there is no *general* sense of "overnight" attached to **express**; you have to ask the particular courier what their express delivery guarantees.